# Negated null coalescing operator (double question mark - ??)

Tags: php, php-7

I want to do this

```
if( !$result['success'] ?? false){
... //handle error case
```

But it doesn't work. Why not?

Workaround is this:

```
        $isSuccess = $result['success'] ?? false;
        if((!$isSuccess){
... //handle error case
```

Is there a better workaround?

Test to reproduce:

```
<?php

$a = [];
$x = !$a['x'] ?? 'bbb';

echo $x;
```

2 problems. Throws a notice. And: echos '1'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can group the expression you're trying to negate.

```
if (!($result['success'] ?? false)) {
```

It's an [operator precedence](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) issue. The negation is of higher precedence than the null coalesce, so it is evaluated before.

So with the example `$x = !$a['x'] ?? 'bbb';`

We're saying "if `!$a['x']` is null then `'bbb'`". Well, `$a['x']` *is* null, since it's undefined, but `!$a['x']` *isn't* null, it is actually `true` (because `!null === true`), so the part of the expression after ?? is never evaluated.

You see 1 because that's the string representation of `true`.

---

If it was mine, I would write it instead as

```
if (empty($result['success'])) {
```

since `empty` will check for existence and truthiness simultaneously.